# Can I replace my device's bootloader to grub?

Tags: boot, bootloader

Basically the title contains everything. I have an old smartphone lying around and I would like to change its bootloader.

How can I know in which partition does it lie?
How can I compile grub on my main machine and install it to my device?

My device implements the Armv7 instruction set.

Note: I do not wish to unlock the stock bootloader, I wish to replace it completely.

Comment: Which device you have?

Comment: Does it matter? I want the instructions to be as generic as possible because I want to perform the same operation on a couple devices.

Comment: yes on different devices different things are loaded for device to work

Comment: @GeorgeD, yes it matters a great deal, because the method for changing a bootloader will vary wildly across devices. But in general, loading GRUB on *most* ARM devices will likely be impossible or extremely difficult due to configurations made by the manufacturers. GRUB does support ARM, so that's not the problem.

Comment: It's this one: http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_mini-3947.php